# Pick last row of a matrix for which the second part of the row is smaller then a certain value

Tags: list-manipulation

Lets say there is a `matrix={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}`. Im interested on the position of the last row, for which the second element of that row is strictly smaller then a certain value n.

If `n=7`,then `Position[matrix]=2` hence `8>7` but `5<7`.
If `n=5`, then `Position[matrix]=1` hence `8>5` and `5=5` but `2<5`.

Comment: Try: `Position[ m[[All, 2]], x_ /; x < n] // Last`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you want any of this parameterized (like change "second element" to "third element" or whatever), but you might proceed like this:

```
Max[Position[matrix[[All, 2]], _?(LessThan[val])]]
```

Or if it matters how many comparisons you do, maybe:

```
Length[matrix] - LengthWhile[Reverse[matrix[[All, 2]]], GreaterEqualThan[val]]
```

(where `val` is the comparison value).